# update multiple home screen widget from activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have 2 widgets on my home screen. I know how to update the single widget from my Main activity. The following code updates my single widget when i press the back button on my Main activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, todo_widget.class);
    intent.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
    int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication())
            .getAppWidgetIds(
                    new ComponentName(getApplication(),         todo_widget.class));
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
    sendBroadcast(intent);}
```

But both the widgets are not updating  if i put my code like this :-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, todo_widget.class);
    intent.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
    int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication())
            .getAppWidgetIds(
                    new ComponentName(getApplication(),     todo_widget.class));
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, todo_widget2.class);
    intent1.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
    int[] ids1 = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication())
            .getAppWidgetIds(
                    new ComponentName(getApplication(), todo_widget2.class));
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids1);
    sendBroadcast(intent1);
    this.finish();
}
```

please someone help me out of this. How do I update both the widgets when i press the back button or when my Main activity is created?